# How to access database stored in array, specially particular rows and columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am using Laravel 5.1. I have stored by database table in an array. Now, I don't know how to access that array by row or column. How to get particular data from array which is required by me from array?

Please tell me how to do that.

```
    $silver_plans = array();
    $silver_plans =  DB::select('select * from ins_gold ');

//  print_r($silver_plans[0]);

//  print_r($silver_plans['0']['age_band']);
```

This is code which is applied by me. I tried to access `age_column`.

Comment: just chain the `->get()` method, should return a collection you need. man, it even just take a second to look at the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) vs creating a question here on SO

Comment: i dont know about that stuff bro... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get() to cast it to collection and iterate the array to access the values:

```
 $silver_plans =  DB::select('select * from ins_gold')->get();
 $silver_plans = $silver_plans->toArray();

 foreach($silver_plans as $plan){
    // your code goes here
    var_dump($plan);
 }
```

Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: @Sarbjyot Singh Chahal: Yes, var_dump the $plan array to check keys and values.

Comment: thanks buddy..... how we can acces in array like... for example i want to acces 3rd row and 4th column

Comment: When you will iterate $silver_plans, you can access each rows as $plan. So $plan will denote a single record, so can access the particular attribute as $plan['your attribute']

Answer (score 0):

you can loop by foreach like this:

```
foreach($silver_plans as $row){
    echo $row->field_name;
}
```

Comment: field_name is the name of column @SarbjyotSinghChahal

Comment: how we can use where and between in this array $silver_plans